# How to format the series data date value to compare with database field?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts with this code to display dates in the x-axis which it gets from the data series. I'd like to compare these dates against a field in a database, and if a match exists run through the formatter condition to display the icon where a match exists. How do I set the return value to match the date formats in the series? Thanks

[See in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/CtAHV/2/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {        
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b', this.value);
                if (checkDatabase(this.value)) {
                    return '&nbsp;<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"/>';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [ [Date.UTC(2011, 11, 4), 21],[Date.UTC(2011, 11, 3), 27],[Date.UTC(2011, 10, 11), 19] ]
    }]
});

    function checkDatabase(val) {
    // Connect and query the db
    return val === 'Saturday, Dec 3, 2011';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example the `checkDatabase()`is never invoked, there is a `return` statement just ahead of it. But I guess that is not the actual question here..

The `===` ([strict equal operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)) will not do type conversion, so what happens here is that the timestamp, e.g. `Date.UTC(2011, 11, 4)` (which is the number of milliseconds from 1970, see [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)) is being compared with the string `'Saturday, Dec 3, 2011'` and that will always return `false`.

For the comparison to work either turn both timestamps to numbers:

```
1322956800000 === Date.UTC(2011, 11, 4) // true
```

or compare the strings:

```
'Sun, 04 Dec 2011 00:00:00 GMT' === new Date(Date.UTC(2011, 11, 4)).toUTCString() // true
```